# How can I get all the combinations of six dice that equal 7?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, dice

This is a homework assignment where I'm supposed to roll 6 dice, then pick out ANY combination of dice that make 7 and discard them all. 
EX. 1,1,1,1,1,2. My score would be 0 because I have to discard all six dice.

At first I believed it was any combination of 2 dice but have now been told otherwise. My code right now reflects the 2 dice and I have no idea how to wrap my head around doing all six without just using brute force with it and writing in every single possible combination and checking for that.

```
        private void calculateScore(){
            //checks for 7's, calculates score if none, updates values  
            discardDieMessage = "Discard Dice. Combinations of die equals 7";

            boolean noSevens = true;
            //diceRoll is an array with 6 values
            for(int i = 0; i<diceRoll.length;i++){
                int temp = diceRoll[i];
                for(int j = 0; j<diceRoll.length;j++){
                    if(temp + diceRoll[j] == 7){noSevens = false;}
                }
            }

            if(noSevens){
                playerScore[playerNumber] = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < diceRoll.length;i++) {
                    playerScore[playerNumber] += diceRoll[i];
                }
                playerScoreString = new String ("Your score is: " + 
                                + playerScore[playerNumber] +
                                "\nYou rolled: " + currentPlayerRolls + " time(s)");    
                update();
                outputTextArea.setText(playerScoreString);
                calculateButton.setDisable(true);
                messageLabel.setText("");
            }
            else {
                messageLabel.setText(discardDieMessage);    
                messageLabel.setTextFill(Paint.valueOf("red"));
            }
        }
```

UPDATE_1: This is the complete code I have so far. It's a 7's Game where a player rolls 6 dice, they must discard dice that equal 7 EX.{3,2,1,1} while the other two die are {6,6} so the remaining dice no longer are equal to 7.

```
//all-gui imports
    import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;
    //GUI specific controls
    import javafx.scene.control.Button;
    import javafx.scene.control.Label;
    import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
    import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
    import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
    //GUI specific containers
    import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
    import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
    import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
    import javafx.geometry.Pos;
    import javafx.geometry.HPos;
    //EventHandler Interface
    import javafx.event.EventHandler;
    import javafx.event.ActionEvent;

    import java.util.Random;
    import javafx.scene.paint.*;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.stream.*;
    import java.io.*;
    /***************************************************************************/
    public class SevensGameGUI extends Application {

        //declare the scene and main stage
        private Stage primaryStage;
        private Scene scene;
        //declare the handler
        private SevensGameHandler handler;
        //declare panes going to be used
        private BorderPane mainPane;
        private GridPane topPane;
        private GridPane centerPane;
        private GridPane outputPane;
        private HBox bottomPane;

        //declare up labels, boxes, buttons, and textAreas
        private Button rollButton;
        private Button calculateButton;
        private Button endButton;
        private Button[] discardButton;

        private Label playerNumberLabel;
        private Label totalPlayersLabel;
        private Label rollNumberLabel;
        private Label maxRollLabel;

        private TextField[] diceTextField;//Dice TextFields
        private TextField playerNumberTextField; //What player is currently playing
        private TextField totalPlayersTextField;
        private TextField rollNumberTextField; //What roll the player is on
        private TextField maxRollTextField; //The total rolls a player has availiable
        private Label messageLabel; //Display error
        private TextArea outputTextArea;

        //setting up program-specfic variables
        private int MAX_THROWS = 3;
        private int[] playerScore;
        private int[] diceRoll;
        private int[] discardDie;
        private int DICE_COUNT;
        private int playerNumber;
        private int firstPlayerRolls;
        private int currentPlayerRolls;
        private int winningPlayer;
        Random generator = new Random();
        private String cannotRollMessage = "";
        private String playerScoreString = "";
        private String discardDieMessage = "";
    /***************************************************************************/   
        public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
            startUP();
            sculptGUI();
            prepareGame();
        }
    /***************************************************************************/
        private class SevensGameHandler implements EventHandler<ActionEvent>{
            public void handle(ActionEvent ae){
                if(ae.getSource() == rollButton){
                    rollDice();
                }else if(ae.getSource() == calculateButton){
                    calculateScore();
                }else if(ae.getSource() == endButton){
                    nextPlayer();
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < discardButton.length; i++){
                    if(ae.getSource() == discardButton[i]){
                        diceRoll[i] = 0;
                        update();
                        discardButton[i].setDisable(true);  
                    }   
                }
            }
        }//end of SevensGameHandler
    /***************************************************************************/
        private void rollDice(){    
            calculateButton.setDisable(false);
            //rolls dice, shows updated values  
            for (int i = 0; i < diceRoll.length; i++) {
            //this rolls the dice 6 times and checks if the button is disabled
                if(!discardButton[i].isDisable()){diceRoll[i] = (generator.nextInt(6)+ 1);}
            }
            //increments how many times the first player rolls
            if (playerNumber == 0) {
                firstPlayerRolls++;
            }
            currentPlayerRolls++;
            //checking updated values and sends error message if so
            if (currentPlayerRolls == MAX_THROWS) {
                cannotRollMessage = ("Error: Player " + 
                            (playerNumber + 1) + " cannot roll anymore!");
                messageLabel.setText(cannotRollMessage);
                messageLabel.setTextFill(Paint.valueOf("red"));
                rollButton.setDisable(true);
            }
            update();
        }
    /***************************************************************************/
        private void calculateScore(){

            //checks for 7's, calculates score if none, updates values  
            discardDieMessage = "Discard Dice. Combinations of die equals 7";

            boolean noSevens = true;
            //diceRoll is an array with 6 values
            for(int i = 0; i<diceRoll.length;i++){
                int temp = diceRoll[i];
                for(int j = 0; j<diceRoll.length;j++){
                    if(temp + diceRoll[j] == 7){noSevens = false;}
                }
            }

            if(noSevens){
                playerScore[playerNumber] = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < diceRoll.length;i++) {
                    playerScore[playerNumber] += diceRoll[i];
                }
                playerScoreString = new String ("Your score is: " + 
                                + playerScore[playerNumber] +
                                "\nYou rolled: " + currentPlayerRolls + " time(s)");    
                update();
                outputTextArea.setText(playerScoreString);
                calculateButton.setDisable(true);
                messageLabel.setText("");
            }
            else {
                messageLabel.setText(discardDieMessage);    
                messageLabel.setTextFill(Paint.valueOf("red"));
            }
        }
    /***************************************************************************/
        private void nextPlayer(){
            //increments player, resets rolls and such, updates values
            if (playerNumber == 0) {
                MAX_THROWS = firstPlayerRolls;  
            }
            playerNumber++;
            clearBoard();
            update();
            calculateButton.setDisable(false);
            rollButton.setDisable(false);
            for (int i = 0; i < DICE_COUNT; i++){
            discardButton[i].setDisable(false);
            }
            outputTextArea.clear();

            for(int i = 0;i<playerScore.length;i++){
                if(playerScore[i] > playerScore[winningPlayer]){
                    winningPlayer = i;
                }
            }
            outputTextArea.appendText("\n\tPlayer " + Integer.toString(winningPlayer+1)+
                " is Winning with " + Integer.toString(playerScore[winningPlayer])+" Points");

            if ( playerNumber == playerScore.length){
                endGame();  
            }
        }//end of nextPlayer()
    /***************************************************************************/
        private void endGame(){
            //sets up a seperate pane to display the winning player along with player scores
            TextArea scoreArea = new TextArea();
            Button closeButton = new Button("Close");
            GridPane endPane = new GridPane();
            scoreArea.setPrefSize(300,350);
            endPane.setHgap(15);
            endPane.setVgap(5);
            endPane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
            endPane.add(scoreArea,0,0);
            endPane.add(closeButton,0,1);
            endPane.setHalignment(closeButton ,HPos.CENTER);
            endPane.setHalignment(scoreArea ,HPos.CENTER);
            Scene endScene = new Scene(endPane,500,500);
            primaryStage.setScene(endScene);
            primaryStage.show();
            closeButton.setOnAction(e -> {
                System.exit(0);
            });

            //output scores and player info
            scoreArea.appendText("Player \t Score\n\n");

            for(int i = 0;i<playerScore.length;i++){
                scoreArea.appendText("Player " + Integer.toString(i+1) +"\t " + 
                Integer.toString(playerScore[i]) + "\n");
            }
            scoreArea.appendText("\n\tCongratulations Player " +
            Integer.toString(winningPlayer+1) + "\n\tYOU WIN!");
        }
    /***************************************************************************/   
        private void prepareGame(){
            //Prepares the game for the player to use by initializing variables 
            //and handlers
            playerScore = new int[] {0,0,0,0,0};
            diceRoll = new int[] {0,0,0,0,0,0};
            discardDie = new int[] {0,0,0,0,0,0};
            DICE_COUNT = 6;
            playerNumber = 0;
            firstPlayerRolls = 0;
            currentPlayerRolls = 0;
            winningPlayer =0;

            update();

            handler = new SevensGameHandler();
            rollButton.setOnAction(handler);
            calculateButton.setOnAction(handler);
            endButton.setOnAction(handler);
            for(int i = 0;i < discardButton.length; i++) {
            discardButton[i].setOnAction(handler);
            }

        }
    /***************************************************************************/
        private void clearBoard(){
            //Method used to reset and update the GUI
            for (int i = 0; i < diceRoll.length; i++) {
            diceRoll[i] = 0;
            discardDie[i] = 0;
            }
            currentPlayerRolls = 0;
            rollButton.setDisable(false);
            messageLabel.setText("");
            outputTextArea.setText("");
            playerNumberTextField.setText(Integer.toString(playerNumber + 1));
            totalPlayersTextField.setText(Integer.toString(playerScore.length));
            rollNumberTextField.setText(Integer.toString(currentPlayerRolls));
            maxRollTextField.setText(Integer.toString(MAX_THROWS));
        }
    /***************************************************************************/
        private void update() {
            //Method used to update the GUI
            for (int i = 0; i < diceTextField.length; i++) {
            diceTextField[i].setText(Integer.toString(diceRoll[i]));
            }
            outputTextArea.setText("");
            calculateButton.setDisable(false);
            playerNumberTextField.setText(Integer.toString(playerNumber + 1));
            totalPlayersTextField.setText(Integer.toString(playerScore.length));
            rollNumberTextField.setText(Integer.toString(currentPlayerRolls));
            maxRollTextField.setText(Integer.toString(MAX_THROWS - currentPlayerRolls));
            }
    /***************************************************************************/
        private void startUP() {
        //Buttons
            rollButton = new Button ("ROLL");
            calculateButton = new Button ("CALCULATE");
            endButton= new Button ("END TURN");

            discardButton = new Button[6];
            for (int i = 0; i < discardButton.length; i++){
            discardButton[i] = new Button("Discard " + (i+1));
            }
        //Labels
            playerNumberLabel = new Label("Player #");
            totalPlayersLabel = new Label("Total Players");
            rollNumberLabel = new Label("Roll #");
            maxRollLabel = new Label("Remaining Rolls");
        //TextFields
            diceTextField = new TextField[6];
            for (int k = 0; k < diceTextField.length; k++){
            diceTextField[k] = new TextField("");
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < diceTextField.length; j++) {
            diceTextField[j].setDisable(true);
            }   
            playerNumberTextField = new TextField ();
            playerNumberTextField.setDisable(true);
            totalPlayersTextField = new TextField ();
            totalPlayersTextField.setDisable(true);
            rollNumberTextField = new TextField ();
            rollNumberTextField.setDisable(true);
            maxRollTextField = new TextField ();
            maxRollTextField.setDisable(true);
            messageLabel = new Label ();
            outputTextArea = new TextArea();

            topPane = new GridPane();
            centerPane = new GridPane();
            outputPane = new GridPane();
            bottomPane = new HBox();
            mainPane = new BorderPane();
        }
    /***************************************************************************/
        private void sculptGUI() {
            //setting textFields parameters
            playerNumberLabel.setPrefWidth(85);
            totalPlayersLabel.setPrefWidth(85);
            rollNumberLabel.setPrefWidth(85);
            maxRollLabel.setPrefWidth(85);

            for (int i = 0; i < diceTextField.length; i++) {
            diceTextField[i].setPrefWidth(50);
            }
            playerNumberTextField.setPrefWidth(85);
            totalPlayersTextField.setPrefWidth(85);
            maxRollTextField.setPrefWidth(85);
            rollNumberTextField.setPrefWidth(85);
            outputTextArea.setPrefSize(300,350);
            //sculpting topPane with GUI elements
            topPane.setHgap(15);
            topPane.setVgap(5);
            topPane.setPrefHeight(100);
            topPane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
                //placement of top pane
            topPane.add(playerNumberLabel, 0, 0);
            topPane.add(playerNumberTextField, 0, 1);
            topPane.add(totalPlayersLabel, 1, 0);
            topPane.add(totalPlayersTextField, 1, 1);
            topPane.add(maxRollLabel, 2, 0);
            topPane.add(maxRollTextField, 2, 1);
            topPane.add(rollNumberLabel, 3, 0);
            topPane.add(rollNumberTextField, 3, 1);
            //sculpting centerPane with GUI elements
            centerPane.setHgap(20);
            centerPane.setVgap(5);
            centerPane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
            centerPane.setHalignment(messageLabel ,HPos.CENTER);
                //placements in top line 
            centerPane.add(diceTextField[0], 0, 0);
            centerPane.add(discardButton[0], 0, 1);
            centerPane.add(diceTextField[1], 0, 2);
            centerPane.add(discardButton[1], 0, 3);
                //placement in 2nd line 
            centerPane.add(diceTextField[2], 1, 0);
            centerPane.add(discardButton[2], 1, 1);
            centerPane.add(diceTextField[3], 1, 2);
            centerPane.add(discardButton[3], 1, 3);
                //placement in 3rd line
            centerPane.add(diceTextField[4], 2, 0);
            centerPane.add(discardButton[4], 2, 1);
            centerPane.add(diceTextField[5], 2, 2);
            centerPane.add(discardButton[5], 2, 3);
            centerPane.add(messageLabel, 0, 4, 3, 1);
            //added seperate pane to house the output in one cell,
            //and the dice controls in another (for proper centering)
            outputPane.add(centerPane,0,0);
            outputPane.add(outputTextArea, 0, 1);
            outputPane.setHgap(20);
            outputPane.setVgap(5);
            outputPane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
            //sculpting bottomPane with GUI elements
            bottomPane.setSpacing(25);
            bottomPane.getChildren().addAll(rollButton, calculateButton, endButton);
            bottomPane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
            bottomPane.setPrefHeight(100);
            //setting the main display with seperate panes
            mainPane.setTop(topPane);
            mainPane.setCenter(outputPane);
            mainPane.setBottom(bottomPane);
            //setting up the scene and stage
            scene = new Scene(mainPane, 500, 500);
            primaryStage = new Stage();
            primaryStage.setTitle ("Sevens Game (Craps) GUI");
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        }//end of sculptGUI
    /***************************************************************************/
    }//end of SevensGameGUI
```

Comment: If you have {1, 6, 3, 4, 5, 2} are you supposed to remove all sevens, or just one?  If you have {3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2} are you supposed to remove a 3 and two 2s, or are you supposed to remove all of the 2s because any of them could potentially be part of a 7?

Comment: Imagine you have (1,1,5,2,...) and you proceed removing 5 and 2. Can you consider them to be "out", or should you reinsert them in and further pick out 5, 1 and 1 ? In the first case 1 and 1 would be left in while in the second, they would not. Please clarify this point.

Comment: I'm supposed to remove ALL combinations of 7's, so in the first example you have listed {1,6,3,4,5,2} you'd have to get rid of all of them. In the 2nd example {3,2,2,2,2,2} discard one 3 and two 2's. Once they are discarded they will go into a discard array (don't have yet) and later be checked if the discard array equals 7. Once the original are discarded the die value will = 0.

Comment: If you had {3, 3, 1, 6, 4, 2} should you be removing {3, 3, 1}, {1, 6}, {3, 4} or {1, 4, 2}? They all add to 7 but once you've removed one the others no longer do. The problem seems non-deterministic to me.

Comment: So, the user gets to decide which dice they want to discard. The total will be the same(19) without discarding. So if they get rid of the {3,3,1} they will not have to get rid of any others because the other 3 die don't add to 7. This is where the user input will vary. A smart user will take away the 3,3,1 and get the higher score where as another user might discard {1,6} & {4,3} and get a lower score without thinking.

Comment: @sprinter makes a great point. Once the problem is more clearly defined it seems like the type that would lend itself well to dynamic programming techniques. Essentially break it down into smaller sub-problems and choose among the sub-problems based on some criteria.